# Unable to display map using mapbox with pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, mapbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0ury.jpg)

As the title and picture shown above, I am having issues to display the map on my website. I looked around for solutions but none is similar to mine. One thing to note is I am using pug (template to write JS in HTML). Here is the code for the JS shown below

```js
/* eslint-disable */
const locations = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("map").dataset.locations);

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'xxxxxx';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'xxxxxxx',
    center: [-118.315192, 34.006905],
    zoom: 10
});
```

Here is the code I am using to implement the top code to display the map on my website.

```js
    section.section-map
        //- Data-location set in dataset in mapbox.js
        #map(data-locations=`${JSON.stringify(tours.locations)}`)
```

Here is my main content

```js
doctype html
html
    head
        block head
            meta(charset='UTF-8')
            meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' value="script-src 'self' api.mapbox.com;")
            title Natours | #{tours.name} Tour
            link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css')
            link(rel='shortcut icon' type='image/png' href='/img/favicon.png')
            link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,700')

    body
        // HEADER

        include _header
        
        // CONTENT

        block content
            h1 This is a placeholder heading

        // FOOTER

        include _footer
            script(src="/js/mapbox.js")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like there is problem with your content security policy set on header..

add following code inside meta tag.

```
script-src 'self' api.mapbox.com;
```

for more info [Read Content Security Policy](https://content-security-policy.com/)

because OP using third party npm module `helmet` ...

for now you can disable the CSP in helmet as following..

```
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: false,
  })
);
```

for more read docs [Helmet Docs](https://helmetjs.github.io/)

Comment: Could you give an example how do it add it. I am using pug the context might be different. This is my meta tag at the moment   meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' value="script-src 'self' api.mapbox.com;")

Comment: could you provide the complete meta tags from your head

Comment: I think your using express with nodejs an npm module that adding CSP dynamically.. make sure are you using npm module helmet or somthing similair ?

Comment: Yeah. I am using helmet at the moment. But its empty. Do I need to include something inside ?

Comment: yeah !! its working now finally. But just on a side note, what do you mean for now ?

Comment: CSP is importing policy for security you can disable it for now... but make sure you read full documents for CSP and npm module helmet how to use CSP in you application.

Answer (score 0):

You have a content security policy Header is missing just put this meta tag in the header it works for me

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' api.mapbox.com;worker-src blob: ;connect-src https://*.tiles.mapbox.com https://api.mapbox.com https://events.mapbox.com">
```